# Special underline/Partial box

Tags: text-decorations, underline, fbox

I'm not exactly sure what to call this, but I'd like to know how to replicate the text decoration shown under the `$n$` in the image. It seems a hooked underline or similar to, a partial box, but only around the character. But I have no idea which packages to even start looking in for it.

[image: S(\pi) definition]

Comment: Perhaps analogous to `$n\rfloor$` using the `amssymb` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One proposal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\partialbox}[1]{%
\underline{#1}\raisebox{-1.1pt}{\rule[-0.5pt]{0.5pt}{4pt}}}
\begin{document}
 $S(\pi)=:\left(\partialbox{n}\dots\right)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: A rather close reproduction of your scan.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\partialbox}[1]{%
\underline{#1}\raisebox{-1.1pt}{\rule[-0.5pt]{0.5pt}{4pt}}}
\begin{document}
 $S(\pi)=:\left(\partialbox{n},\,\to_\pi,\,\le_\pi\right)$
\end{document}
```

[image]